# WordPress Как узнать что плагин платный?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть задача на стороннем сайте (с которым не велась разработка персонально Вами) узнать являеться ли текущий Активный плагин в платной или безплатной версии. Возможно ли это сделать програмным методом?

Предположим, что у вас есть много времени, а количество плагинов настолько большое, что пройтись по ним руками, и проверять установлена там лицензия подключения или нет, нету возможности.

Это обстрактная задача, в которой хочеться понять, чем именно платная версия отличаеться от бесплатной? Возможно есть какой-то общий критерий по которому это можно понять, предположим все платные версии обязаны использовать какойто хук в подключении к ядру... ?

Answer (score 2):

Универсального способа нет и быть не может. Ибо для плагинов вне [репозитория](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) "закон не писан".

Можно лишь точно узнать есть ли плагин в репо.

Comment: бесплатные плагины ведь тоже есть в репозитории. Что это даст ?  Я думал в сторону какой-то особой функции которая ТОЧНО должна сделать запрос на стороний ресурс и дождаться положительного ответа, прежде чем дальше продолжить выполнения... Есть ведь при добавлении плагинов в https://wordpress.org/plugins/  какие-то требования , может что-то связаное с безопасностью ?

Comment: не "тоже", а в репо **только** бесплатные плагины. И да, условий попаданий туда куча. Из поданных заявок модерацию проходит едва треть.

Comment: аааа, дошло ви про публичные репозитории.

Comment: У ВП существует  **единственный** [официальный  репозиторий плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

Способ что приходит на ум - искать в HTML коде страницы теги, который вставляет лишь платная версия плагина. Но это возможно только если работа плагина касается визуальной составляющей

Comment: _"искать в HTML коде страницы теги, который вставляет лишь платная версия плагина"_ -- это как?)

Comment: Ну-ка расскажи нам про эти секретные теги. "Для визуальной составляющей" особенно интересно.

Comment: Ну элементарно. Например существует (на самом деле нет) какойто платный плагин, который позволяет оставлять комментарии к записям, используя vk api. Соответственно в коде, после каждой записи появляются в этом случае теги вида <div id="vkontakte-comments-6606" class="vkfull-comments"...

Comment: Ну, для начала, Вы это как будете искать? Через инструменты разработчика? Проще тогда уже пройтись руками по плагинам. И это весьма неуниверсально, так как очень велика вероятность, что там будут довольно абстрактные обертки и имена классов и Вы не сможете это определить, кроме как точно знать, что искать.

Comment: Нет ничего проще получить исходный код страницы. Например: $html=file_get_contents("https://мойсайт");. А уж найти тэги в $html автоматизировать я думаю очень просто

Comment: И, что Вы конкретно там будете искать? Очень просто автоматизировать, когда не знаешь что конкретно ищешь. Например сайте используется какой-то платный плагин из CodeCanyon. А через `file_get_contents()` все записи/страницы/пост тайпы будете прогонять?

Comment: Ну естественно, конечно нужно знать какие именно платные плагины ищешь. Если не знаешь что искать так и искать смысла нет )

Comment: Вы вопрос читали?) _"количество плагинов настолько большое, что пройтись по ним руками, и проверять установлена там лицензия подключения или нет, нету возможности."_ -- наверное если нет времени по ним в админке походить, то поискать какие там айдишники или классы навешиваются, думаю что тем более. Если ты уже знаешь что плагин платный и он у меня установлен, на кой черт мне парсить свой сайт?

Comment: Я предположил, что у него мильон сайтов которые нужно автоматизированно проверить на наличии определенного набора плагинов

Comment: >используя vk api. ОМГ.. какую же чушь ты пишешь.. Я написал плагин - пипа хелодолли или катсомный тип контента (если ты вообще понимаешь как пишутся плагины и что это вообще такое) и продаю его. Какое нафик вк-апи? Какие "теги".. Иди уже мимо, не позорься.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, на странице плагинов, у тех что из репозитория есть ссылка "Детали". Там есть ссылка на страницу в репозитории. Если нет, то обчно ставят ссылку на сайт разработчика и там уже видно - платный он или нет. Ну а если вообще нет ссылок, то наверное - самопис.